# How can I import JSON fields to a Wordpress page? (mapping 2 fields to title and content)

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Hi I multiple JSON files containing multiple values and keys and I wish to import them and map 2 values/keys to become the title and content of multiple Wordpress pages.

Here is an example of one of the JSON files:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Content",
        "type": "group",
        "variables": [
            {
                "name": "Title",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "The title that will become the content in the Wordpress page."
            },
            {
                "name": "Description",
                "type": "string",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Promoted",
                "type": "boolean",
                "value": false
            },
            {
                "name": "Main",
                "type": "content",
                "value": {
                    "text": "<h2>Some text here<br><\/h2><p>The content that will become the content in the Wordpress page.<\/p>",
                    "components": [],
                    "images": []
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Top Content",
                "type": "content",
                "value": {
                    "text": "",
                    "components": [],
                    "images": []
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How should I proceed? The json files are on my computer and I want to import the content to the remote Wordpress DB.

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you upload them into their own folder:

```
 $files= scandir('your directory path'); 

 foreach($files as $file):
      $json= json_decode( file_get_contents($file) );

      // create your post array here... 
      // e.g. $content= $json['content']; 

      wp_insert_post($post);
 endforeach;
 $array= json_decode($json);
```

You have a bit of work to do, you need to figure out you want to insert, look up wp_insert_post and try and access the content from the $json array. If all the files are formatted differently, you are going to have issues here!

Comment: The json files are on my computer and I want to import the content to the remote Wordpress DB.

Comment: how many files are you talking about? is this a one time action to complete? obviously you will need them on your server to work with them, whether you ftp them or upload them using a form will make a difference on the approach.

Comment: I have 60-80 pages ... I can FTP them or whatever. What do you suggest? One time action.

Comment: OK thank you very very much. This looks great. I will test this in about 2-3 hours and come back to give you my results! Thanks again.